# recovery data from internal storage

Tags: android, data-recovery, internal-storage

I wrote an Android app. Export as signed APK sent via mail installed to device.- not at Market.

At runtime it will save they data to internal storage  with similar code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

As I know - correct me if I am wrong - it is saved to /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/FILENAME

Because it is saved with `MODE_PRIVATE` I am not sure if any other app from Market or mine can  see it save it. Maybe **if I create an app with the same signature?**

The phone it is not rooted. I have tryed many backup, copy with app and ADB shell. 
App didn't saved my file, adb shell gave permission denied.

Is there any solution with programming or not to get that file?

Comment: Since you mentioned it will save the data to internal storage, and your hypothesis is indeed correct, i.e. `/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/FILENAME`, only your app can read it. If rooted, yes, any other app that requests root permission, *provided* they know the package name can traverse the directory and pull in the data and do whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little code part to test it:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText tfData;
    private Button btSave, btLoad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tfData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tfData);
        btSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSave);
        btLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLoad);

        btSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doSave();
            }
        });

        btLoad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doLoad();
            }
        });
        tfData.setText("Some secret data");

        boolean btLoadVisible = false; // TODO change this value for the second build!

        if (!btLoadVisible) {
            btLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            btSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private static final String FILENAME = "private.dat";

    private void doSave() {
        String text = null;
        if (tfData.getText() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a string!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        text = tfData.getText().toString();

        if (text == null || text.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a string!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            fos.close();
            fos = null;
            
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Saved").setMessage("Your data is saved:\n" + text+"\nChange the build to recover it!")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("doSave", "Can't save ...", e);
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // I don't care:
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void doLoad() {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("FileNotFoundException")
                    .setMessage(
                            "The file with data can't be found. Or it wasn't saved at all or you have uninstalled the old app or... who knows.\nI can't recover the data, it is lost permanenty!!!")
                    .setPositiveButton("I am sad", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).show();
            return; // I don't like return from catch...
        }

        if (fis != null) {

            try {
                int size = fis.available();// not the best, but now I hope is possible to read 10-30 bytes without blocking
                byte[] buff = new byte[size];
                int readCount = fis.read(buff);
                if (readCount != size) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Dammit can't read : " + size + " bytes, only " + readCount + ". Restart app, than phone? ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                String text = new String(buff, "UTF-8");
                tfData.setText(text);

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Loaded").setMessage("Your data is recovered:\n" + text)
                        .setPositiveButton("I am happy", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e("doLoad", "Can't load ...", e);

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("IOException").setMessage("There is some error while reading the data:\n" + e.getMessage())
                        .setPositiveButton("I am sad", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).show();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Clean, build, export as signed apk: eg InternalMemoryReader_save.apk

[image]

save the keystore!!!

- change the `boolean btLoadVisible = false` to `boolean btLoadVisible = true` .
- export apk WITH THE SAME KEYSTORE!  but diff name, eg InternalMemoryReader_load.apk  - but can be a _datasaver _factoryservice whatever. This usually it is not given to the user.

[image]

Install the first apk and do a save.

- do not uninstall the apk
- lets propose you are blaming of data loss, can't open it ...and once  in a mail you will receive the _load.apk from the support service. Install it without remove the old apk. It has the same package name, same signature, just diff file name.

  I was able to load the data. It can be send via mail or processed there, the hardest part is done.

**Conclusion:**

If you are the app developer and if you have the keystore and able to sign a modified apk than you will have access to that internal, private file.

I hope I am helping somebody else to to recover his app data and not waste so much time.

If you know better solution, please let me know!